# jax-ws list getter method is not generated

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

I make 2 Object with getter and setter method in my SOAP webservice server

Person

```
public class Person {    
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

ResponsePerson

```
public class ResponsePerson {
        private String response;
        private String responseMessage;
        private List<Person> person;

        public void setResponse(String response){
           this.response = response;
        }

        public String getResponse(){
            return this.response;
        }

         public void setResponseMessage(String message){
           this.responseMessage = message;
        }

        public String getResponseMessage(){
            return this.responseMessage;
        }

        public List<Person> getPersonData(){
            if (this.person == null) {
                this.person = new ArrayList<Person>();
            }
            return this.person;
        }
}
```

---

### This is generated class in SOAP client

Person

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "person", propOrder = {
    "age",
    "name"
})
public class Person {

    protected int age;
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the age property.
     * 
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the age property.
     * 
     */
    public void setAge(int value) {
        this.age = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

ResponsePerson

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "responsePerson", propOrder = {
    "response",
    "responseMessage"
})
public class ResponsePerson {

    protected String response;
    protected String responseMessage;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the response property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the response property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResponse(String value) {
        this.response = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the responseMessage property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResponseMessage() {
        return responseMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the responseMessage property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResponseMessage(String value) {
        this.responseMessage = value;
    }

}
```

I use netbeans as IDE. Anyone can explain me why i don't get the getPersonData method in client ?

Comment: You don't have a field that is called "personData", rename the field "person" to "personData"

Comment: the code that have "personData" is only method here
public List<Person> getPersonData(){}

this is just a method any name is ok i think . .

Comment: It's not, SOAP checks for getters and setters, and it doesn't consider it one, its worth trying...

Comment: Person is an Object not field. It have field name and age. I've change the getter method from getPersonData to getPerson the result is still the same. no getter method for Person in client

Comment: in your "ResponsePerson" class, person is a field!